# Number of distinct substrings in a string

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, substrings, suffix-array

From what I have come to understand, the best way to implement it is to use the suffix  array $S$ of the string $w$ and its LCP-array (Longest Common Prefix) $L$.

The answer can be obtained by

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{|w|} \left( |S[i]| -L[i-1] \right).$$

What I don't get is how and why is this working?

I would be very grateful if someone explained this.

Comment: What's LCP?  What do you mean by "iteration of ...": iteration over what?  Please take some time to edit your question carefully and make sure it is comprehensible and self-contained; right now it is a bit too "stream of consciousness" for me to follow.  Also, I suggest that you edit the question to explain what you have tried, to answer your question on your own.  Have you tried running the algorithm by hand on a few small examples?  Where did you get this proposed algorithm from, and why do you think it is a correct solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a formal proof, I want to give some intuition behind the formula. The suffix array contains all the suffixes of the string $w$. A substring is nothing else than a prefix of a suffix. So if you count $\sum_i |S[i]|$, you will get all the substrings, but of course you overcount the number of *different* substrings.

Let's have a closer look. Assume the $S[i-1]=xyz$ and $S[i]=xyxyz$. By the above counting method the entry $S[i-1]$ counted the substrings $x,xy$ and $xyz$ and the entry $S[i]$ counted $x,xy,xyx,xyxy,xyxyz$. You will notice that since the prefixes of length 2 of both entries are the same we have double counted $x,xy$. But the length of the longest common prefix is stored in $L[i]$ so we subtract it to compensate for the overcounting.

Comment: What is the formula to find the exact number of occurrences of a pattern from the SA and the LCP?

Comment: Count of distinct substrings of a string using Suffix Array http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-substrings-string-using-suffix-array/